# Easymock expect exception?

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have below DAO method.

```
public String getMsg(String name){

 //get data from database 
  if db returned value is null then throw exception.

 if(returnValue == null){
    throw new CustomException("No results");
 }

 return returnValue;
}
```

I need to write a test expected exception scenario as below. How can I write?

Comment: Do you want to test this DAO method or a class that uses this method?

Comment: I want to test the class that is using this DAO. I want to mock this DAO in Service class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `String getMsg(String name)` is an interface method, then:

```
public interface IMsgDAO
{
   // ...
   String getMsg(String name);
   // ...
}
```

In UT

```
IMsgDAO dao = EasyMock.createMock(IMsgDAO.class);  
EasyMock.expect(dao.getMsg((String) EasyMock.anyObject())
   .andThrow(new CustomException()) // <---   
   .anyTimes();
```

Now call of `dao.getMsg("anyString")` will throw exception

Answer (score 0):

You mock the databse connection, and write two test cases. One in which you tell the mocked connection to return null, in which you will expect an exception (@Test(expect = CustomException.class)), and one in which the mocked connection returns a dummy result, and the test does not fail since there is no exception.

On a side note, I think by including the validation logic in your DAO breaks the single responsibility principle. In my opinion either the underlying database connection should throw the exception, or you should separate out the validation logic and put it in a void validate(? toValidate) method, that should throw the exception if the parameter is not valid.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to mock the DAO and test service method which uses this DAO method.

Comment: Then http://stackoverflow.com/a/26422113/2921283 is spot on. On a side note: you do not necessarily need an interface to mock an object, but there are two gotchas: you can't mock static nor final, and be mindful when you use matchers in the mocks behaviour definition: you can't mix matchers and regular params. Also you need a 'replay(...)' between behavior definition (recording phase) and testing.